# Trouble accessing $scope from a ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ng-view

When the site runs I only see the headers and instead of the #outerBox div (contains my ng-repeat) I see

```
<!-- ngRepeat: list in $parent.lists -->
```

Here is my code

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

module.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/:num',
      {
        templateUrl: "list.html",
        controller: "ListController"
      }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

module.service('ListService', function ($http, $routeParams) {

    this.getLists = function () {
        return $http.get("testmysql.php", {params : {num : $routeParams.num}})
        .then(function(results){
            //Success;
            console.log(results.data);
            return results.data;
        }, function(results){
            //error
            console.log("Error: " + results.data + "; "
                                  + results.status);
            return results.data;
        });
    }
});

module.controller("ListController", function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, ListService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous){
        ListService.getLists().then(function(data){
            $scope.lists = data;
        });
    });
});
```

The body of index.html...

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

And list.html

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 id="websiteTitle">Website</h1>
    <h2 id="slogan">The only site you'll ever need</h2>
    <!-- View below contains unique id from URL -->
    <div class="outerBox" ng-repeat="list in lists">
    <div class="innerBox">
        <h1 class="listTitle">{{list[0].listname}}</h1>
        <div class="website" ng-repeat="site in list">
        <span class="index">{{$index + 1}}</span><a href = {{site.url}}><img src= "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{site.url}}">{{site.name}}</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont know why I cannot access the scope. I tried $rootscope.test = "test" in my controller. Then when I did {{test}} it DID work in list.html. But no luck with ng-repeat.

Also note that if I have a template of "" and put my list.html HTML into the body of the index file everything works perfectly, but I dont want that because I need 2 views.

**Solved**: $rootScope.$on was my problem, it betrayed me.Removing it fixed it.

Comment: Add whatever console.log(results.data); is outputting that'll make this a lot easier to follow with the data at that point. Also, is there a reason for the $routscope.on listener? is that actually firing? Unless there is some specific reason for it you can probably lose it and it might be causing your problem. It's not needed as the controller won't be executed until after the route is changed anyways. Possibly your problem.

Comment: Have you tested this with some basic array defined in the controller?

Comment: @Lenny console.log(results.data) logs my array of arrays as expected. Yes, it is firing, everything functions if i put list.html into the body of index.html, and if templateUrl changes to template = " ".

Comment: @Lenny Okay so while it is a thing and it WAS working before, after removing it I have my views all working good. Thank you, problem solved.

Comment: eh well looks like you got it resolved, anyhow made a plunkr to show that it all works with some test data http://plnkr.co/edit/24AjjyOr22oDxK4Q1qq5

Comment: @DustinClark you were establishing a listener for route change in the controller AFTER the route was changed. So on the first load it wasn't firing on every change after that it would fire, but the route change is not needed since the controller is initialized on route change anyways.

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks for that! Ill definitely look at it, it might help someone in the future who might stumble onto this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you need the route change listener? There is a chance it is never firing.. try this instead?

```
module.controller("ListController", function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, ListService) {
    ListService.getLists().then(function(data){
        $scope.lists = data;
    });
});
```